# ORA-00904 for ORDER BY in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I can not understand what goes wrong in this query:

```
    select last_name, first_name a from employees
order by "a";
```

Output is:

```
ORA-00904: "a": invalid identifier
```

However this query working and sort results by first_name in ascending order:

```
    select last_name, first_name a from employees
order by "A";
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, Klay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle isn't case sensitive by default.

So, when you say

```
select first_name a from employees
```

Oracle sees that as

```
SELECT FIRST_NAME A FROM EMPLOYEES
```

but when you start using "Quotes"...

```
order by "a"
```

Oracle sees that as

```
ORDER BY "a"
```

a <> A

This isn't a problem if you ensure your quoted objects are also always capitalized, which is why your "A" works but your "a" doesn't.

My advice - just completely remove the quotes on your object names.

```
SELECT LAST_NAME,
       FIRST_NAME A
  FROM EMPLOYEES
 ORDER BY A;
```

[image]